# UIRequiresFullScreen not working

Tags: ios, splitview

I have an app that doesn't work that well with iOS 9's SplitView. I tried to turn it off by checking the "Requires Full Screen" setting in Deployment Info, but that didn't disable SplitView. (I looked, and UIRequiresFullScreen is set to YES in the info.plist).

Any suggestions? This is for iOS 10.

Comment: Are you talking about UISplitView or multi-window support ?

Comment: Multi-window support.

Comment: I have the same problem, have you found a solution since ? I have UIRequiresFullScreen is set to yes,  and landscape as the only orientation supported, yet the slide over view is still appearing.